# Window resizing software

Tags: gratis, window-manager, windows-xp

Working on Windows XP, I'm looking for a software enabling at least the same window control present in Windows 7 and higher. By that, I mean:

- when moving a window on an edge, this window is resize to take half the screen
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (or other directions) places the window on the desired edge

More ideally, I'd like a behaviour similar to Unity on Ubuntu, which gives more control (edges and corners via the num pad).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even on Windows 7 and higher, this behavior is still limited to edges and not corners. I use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) to achieve something similar to Ubuntu. 
Install it and run the following script:

```
#Persistent

SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
SysGet, Mon1, MonitorWorkArea
midH := (Mon1Right-Mon1Left)/2
midV := (Mon1Bottom-Mon1Top)/2

#NumPad1::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , 0, midV, midH, midV
  return
#NumPad2::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , 0, midV, Mon1Right, midV
  return
#NumPad3::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , midH, midV, midH, midV
  return
#NumPad4::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , 0, 0, midH, Mon1Bottom
  return
#NumPad5::
  WinGet, MinMax, MinMax, A
  if (MinMax = 0) {
    WinMaximize, A
  } else {
    WinRestore, A
  }
  return
  WinRestore, A
#NumPad6::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , midH, 0, midH, Mon1Bottom
  return
#NumPad7::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , 0, 0, midH, midV
  return
#NumPad8::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , 0, 0, Mon1Right, midV
  return
#NumPad9::
  WinRestore, A
  WinMove A, , midH, 0, midH, midV
  return
```

It allows you to use <kbd>Win</kbd> + any key on the numpad to move the active window to the corresponding edge/corner, with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Num5</kbd> for maximize/restore

---

Edit:

For a multi-monitor setup, [here is the revised version of the script (Github link)](https://github.com/tymric/resizeWindowToEdge)

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! (for the script and for AH, looks like a useful tool)

Comment: works great for one monitor
How to modify this script for multiple monitors so that it does not return to the main desktop?

Comment: @dodohjk I have updated the answer with the link to a multi-monitor version