# Allow Win+UpArrow and Win+DownArrow to resize and move window to top/bottom of screen

Tags: gratis, windows-7, gui, window-manager

Windows 7 has a great function that allows the user to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to resize and move the current window to the right half of the screen.  It has a similar function using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> to resize and move the current window to the left half of the screen.

As great as this is, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> do not perform the respective functions to resize and move the current window to the top/bottom half of the screen.  (Instead <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> maximizes the window, and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> restores/minimizes the window).

Is there any gratis software that allows the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> keys to resize and move the current window to the top/bottom half of the screen?

Open-source software is preferred, but *not* required.

Comment: In [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13340/6834). I used an AutoHotKey script to bind the resizing to `Win + Num`. You can use the same script, substituting the numbers for arrows

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WinSplit revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/). It allows fully configurable keystrokes to position and resize a window on your monitors.

Comment: WinSplit revolution is now discontinued, however still available in it last version 11.04 through different download sites. For some more information on why it was a great product, see an [archived version of help pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410192349/http://winsplit-revolution.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

I was an active user of [WinSplit Revolution](//www.winsplit-revolution.com/), but this product has been discontinued and the website now links to [MaxTo](//www.maxto.net/). As stated in a comment on another answer you could use the Wayback machine to read an older version of the [help pages for WinSplit Revolution](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410192349/http://winsplit-revolution.com/help), and as a new user of MaxTo I would like to point out some of the differences:

- With WinSplit you could tap the keyboard shortcuts multiple times, and it would behave differently. I.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>1</kbd> would first send your window to the top-left corner convering a quarter of the screen, but the second time it could cover one sixth of the screen. Sizes was configurable
- WinSplit had configured the entire numpad (or number keys) to send the window to that part of the screen, and had a optional little pad to help you send it there, if you didn't feel like using the keyboard
- With MaxTo you define different regions into where you would like to expand the window. You have the option to define different regions for different monitors, and you can store/load different region settings for different monitors
- MaxTo allows for two different settings of regions for each monitor. In my current setup I have both regions to split the monitor, and the main region splits it into two thirds on the left, and one third to the right, whilst the alternate region has the two third on the right, and one third to the left
- Hitting the maximise button in WinSplit gave a full screen window, but in MaxTo the default configuration is to maximise into the current region
- When windows are maximised in MaxTo into a region, you can use extra keyboard shortcuts to rotate within that region (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>)
- The regions are very customisable in MaxTo, and you can divide the screen in way too many regions if you like
- WinSplit was free, but MaxTo cost 19 USD
- Both programs has configurable keyboard shortcuts, including some in combination with the mouse and dragging

All in all MaxTo serves my purposes well when organising windows on my triple monitor setup. I would however like to have an option regarding how the default maximise function of MaxTo works<sup>1</sup>. And WinSplit was/is a neat organiser.

<sub><sup>1</sup> To maximise to the entire screen you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd></sub>