# Display 4 PDFs or more, always updated

Tags: windows, pdf

I am looking for a Windows program that can:

- display 4 PDFs or more simultaneously in the same window (more than 4 would be even better) like in the image below (but ideally with filenames visible somewhere).
- update the PDF whenever the PDF is changed by another program (e.g. like Sumatra PDF does, but I don't want to tile a bunch of Sumatra windows myself).

If possible, free and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: I use SumatraPDF for a similar layout. I tile the windows using keyboard shortcuts from the AutoHotKey script in [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13340/6834). e.g. `Win + Num9` for upper-right corner